# Configure homebrew to compile with specific clang version

Tags: clang, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I need to use the llvm.org version of clang, rather than the Apple version of clang, as the compiler for a specific Homebrew formula. I installed llvm37 with

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install llvm37
```

so I have clang-3.7 at /usr/local/bin. But HOMEBREW_CC can't be set to this path:

```
HOMEBREW_CC=clang-3.7 HOMEBREW_CXX=clang++-3.7 brew install --build-from-source <formula>
Error: Invalid value for HOMEBREW_CC: clang-3.7
```

What are some alternative ways to try forcing Homebrew to use this version of clang in its build environment?

Comment: I don't use Homebrew, as I like Macports, but I found [this exchange of views](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/46161) interesting and I think it's relevant to your issue.